# Mirror image of a diacritic mark

Tags: graphics, rotating

I want to have a mirror image of a diacritic mark. If I use `reflectbox` or `scalebox` the diacritic doesn't attach to the preceding character. I want it to be attached, but in inverse direction.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    á\par
    a\reflectbox{́}\par
    a\scalebox{-1}[1]{́}\par
\end{document}
```

Though Unicode's mechanism doesn't allow this, I wanted to know if there is a way to do this in TeX.

Comment: Why do you not use agrave U+00E0 à  ?

Comment: It is just an example, I want to do it on a diacritic from Devanagari script. This is just for the convenience of other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did experiments with unicode accent and it seems to be alchemy. Maybe it heavily depends on Unicode renderer too. The following example is using OpTeX (because I don't use LaTeX). If you want to use LaTeX then you can use idea and re-write the code. The constant -8.5pt is so called "guess constant":)

```
\fontfam[lmfonts] % use OpTeX

\newbox\gravebox
\setbox\gravebox=
   \hbox{\pdfsave\pdfscale{-1}{1}\hbox to0pt{\hss ́ \kern-8.5pt}\pdfrestore}
\def\grave{\copy\gravebox}

á, à, a\grave, x\grave, but you must raise: b\raise.4ex\grave.

\bye
```

The core of the idea is that the space is accented by Unicode accent, the `hss '\kern` part of the code looks in UTF8 and in hex printing as 70 74 74 **20 cc 81 20** 5c 6b 65 ... The cc 81 is acute accent in UTF8 itself.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I need to use XeLaTeX for rendering Devanagari script. Thus OpTeX won't be useful.

Comment: @Niranjan There is idea presented. You can use this idea in LaTeX too. I hope that it is no problem. OpTeX is only tool which I used to test this idea. LaTeX knows the primitives `\setbox`, `\hbox`, `\kern` `\copy` too.